# SAP NetWeaver Trial Version for 64bit OS?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

Is there a 64bit version out there for 64bit OS? If not, is there a way to install the SAP NetWeaver on a 64bit Windows 7 without using a VM with a 32bit system?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [this developer verion for windows](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads?rid=/library/uuid/70b58216-00e7-2c10-f6a9-c59f3a351b63).

But the requirements state following:

> Operating System: Windows XP
>   Professional (Service Pack 2) or
>   Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista
>   (english)

I did use vm ware with a xp sp 2 image under windows 7 to install the Netweaver server. No problems so far (except for the performance).

Comment: Thats what I ended up with :)

Answer (score 1):

[SAP NetWeaver ABAP Trial 7.02 Win 64-bit Version (SP7)](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads?rid=/webcontent/uuid/d051394c-be7a-2e10-0aa5-978632b2525e) System Requirements:

- Operating System Windows 7 64 bit Professional (unsupported platform for Trial Installation) or Windows Server 2008
- JRE 1.4.x or JRE 1.5.x (for installation only, JRE 1.6 is not supported)
- ...

If you're not logged on, you can find it in the [SAP Software Download Catalog](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

64 bit - yes, for example [this one](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads?rid=/library/uuid/60d6c8b7-5d8f-2910-31bf-ebdf74fefd8b). Windows, I don't know...

Comment: Yeah, thats Linux, I was looking for a Windows version :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest released trial version is the SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP 7.02 SP6 32-bit Trial.
It's available at http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/nw-downloads  There are no 64bit windows trial versions

You can install the 32bit versions on Windows 7 Professional or better by using XP Mode (you can't install XP Mode on Windows 7 Home or lower).   Searvh on "site:microsoft.com Windows XP mode" for how to install xp mode (I can only post 1 link at a time at the moment).